# Fermi-Dirac statistics and electrical filter

Tags: statistical-mechanics, electric-circuits, fermions, quantum-statistics, cryogenics

The graph of Fermi-Dirac distribution near absolute zero and an [electrical filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_filter#Network_synthesis) looks very similar. My question is does: this similarity finds any application?

I can't think of any scenario as such: You pass $\sin(\omega t)+\sin(10 \omega t)$ through a filter and if $10\omega$ lies outside the bandwidth of filter you are left with only $\sin(\omega t)$ signal. While in the case of Fermi-Dirac statistics as you cool down the temperature of the system all the particles arrange themselves in such that their energy lies below Fermi energy so we don't get any rejection which is essential as an application of filter.